# Limit Aviary features

Tags: android, aviary

May I know 'Is it possible to limit Aviary photo editing features'. For instance, I wanna use only adding text feature.

Probably, stupid question. But I cannot find anywhere about that information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the Aviary SDK for Android, you can limit the tools that are available when you start the intent to open the editor activity.
You add them as an extra to the intent. 
So, for your case, it would be:

```
String[] tools = new String[] { "TEXT" };
Intent aviaryIntent = new Intent(activity, FeatherActivity.class);
aviaryIntent.setData(data);
aviaryIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_TOOLS_LIST, tools);
startActivityForResult(aviaryIntent, REQUEST_AVIARY);
```

Customize to your needs, but the key is adding a string array of pre-defined tool names to the intent.

[Documentation found here](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/android/intent-parameters#EXTRA_TOOLS_LIST)

Comment: I have a problem with FilterLoaderFactory.
I don't know where to import FilterLoaderFactory from.

Comment: It looks like they changed the API since that post. I'm not using Aviary anymore, but it doesn't look like you need FilterLoaderFactory anymore. Just make a string array with the tools you want (shown in the documentation. Maybe they are included in the Constants class?)